# clicking menu error does not show the page

Tags: codeigniter

What is the difference between:

http://localhost/gsa/profile/history  -->  (offline)

and

http://www.gsa-constructionspecialist.com/profile/history  (online)

Offline shows:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /gsa/profile/history was not found on this server.

After clicking this menu:

views/0hearder.php

```
  <div id="menu">
        <a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"><h3 class="listmenu" data="1" data-title="home">Home</h3></a>
        <h3 class="listmenu" data="2" data-title="profile">Home</h3>
            <div class="submenu2" style="display:none">
            <?php
                $profile = $this->post_model->post(1);
                if ($profile){
                foreach ($profile as $pro){
            ?>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('profile/'.$pro->post_alias); ?>"><h3 class="submenu" style="<?php echo ($this->uri->segment(2)==$pro->post_alias)?'font-weight:bold':''; ?>"><?php echo $pro->post_title; ?></h3></a>
            <?php } } ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: you may have to set it in routes.php also check you have followed style guide for name files and classes http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Also check when you have uploaded your project o your live website `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.gsa-constructionspecialist.com/';`

Comment: I set my config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/gsa/';                                        site/config/config.php file.                                                                             I thought it should be enough for the file.